# Websocket closed after the app is in background for more than 10 minutes. (React-Native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, websocket

I am creating an app with React-Native and I use websocket to receive data. 
However, when I push home button to make my app in background, the websocket will be paused and when I click my app again, websocket will be continued which is totally fine but my problem is if my app is in background mode for more than 10 minutes and when I open my app again, the websocket is completely stop. How can I solve this problem?

I know I can use Appstate to detect if my app is in background mode. But I think that's not what I really need right now!

And also the other similar question:

What if user stay in the app but their phone locked automatically and when they open their phone again, the websocket has been closed too.
How can I let websocket continue again?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an app that uses websockets, our problem was that in case of our REST server restart, all the clients should reopen the web socket. So we ping the server at a fixed rate using setInterval, and recreate the socket when there are errors, this is the code of our socket  manager class:

```
export default class SocketManager {
  constructor(endPoint, handlers) {
    this.endPoint = endPoint;
    this.handlers = handlers;

    this.createSocket();
  }

  createSocket() {
    if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.socket = this.buildSocket();
    this.pings = 0;
    this.pongs = 0;

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.socket.send("ping");
      this.pings++;
    }, 3000);
  }

  closeSocket = () => {
    console.log("Cerrando socket");
    if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.socket.close();
  };

  reconnect = () => {
    this.createSocket();
  };

  buildSocket = () => {
    const sock = new WebSocket(this.endPoint);
    sock.onerror = error => {
      console.log("error", error);
      setTimeout(() => this.reconnect(), 3000);
    };
    sock.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
      if (data === "pong") {
        this.pongs++;
        console.log(`${this.pings} pings, ${this.pongs}  pongs`);
        return;
      }
      const handler = this.handlers[data];
      if (handler) {
        handler();
      }
    };

    return sock;
  };
}
```

We are calling it from a redux action creator like this:

```
const doLogin = ({ email, password }) => {
  const body = doFormBody({ email, password });
  // // //console.log(`endPoint es ${ENDPOINT}`);

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: CONECTANDO });

    const url = `${ENDPOINT}/rest/login`;
    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
      },
      method: "POST",
      body
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (json.error) dispatch({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, payload: json.error });
        else {
          dispatch({ type: LOGGED_IN, payload: json });
          const adultosSocket = crearSocket(dispatch, json.id);
          dispatch({ type: ESTABLECE_SOCKET, payload: adultosSocket });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, payload: err.message });
      });
  };
};
```

The action uses this helper function to finally create the socket. It was important to keep only one instance of the socket sending pings at any time.

```
const crearSocket = (dispatch, userId) => {
  const endPoint = `${WS_ENDPOINT}/usuarioConectado?userId=${userId}`;
  const handlers = {
    reload: () => {
      const url = `${ENDPOINT}/rest/adultos/${userId}`;
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => dispatch({ type: ADULTOS_CARGADOS, payload: json }))
        .catch(err => dispatch({ type: ADULTOS_ERROR, payload: err.message }));
    }
  };

  return new SocketManager(endPoint, handlers);
};
```

This is not toy code, is actually running in our app, so it works.